# Where do I find an api for live stock CHARTS not prices but charts?

Tags: mobile, charts

I'm trying to build a mobile app that will present a live stock chart. However I cannot find a single API that provides the stock charts not just stock quotes. Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [AFreeChart](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) for drawing stock charts, it has more chart types like, bar, line, candle sticks etc..